# How to use python script in c++ (qt) code? (web-scraping aspect)

Tags: python, c++, qt, web-scraping

I want to build a gui application which allows to convert money with real-time exchange rate. I'm using MacOs and QtCreator (I have also PyCharm and VS Code, but I especially want to use QtCreator to make my gui)

Firstly I've created a Python script which gets me a real-time exchange rate from a stooq page. I did it, because I wanted to learn web Scraping. 
Secondly, I've wanted to make a qui for it and I've already known how to use and write an application in Qt Creator in C++. So, I've created an app. First idea was to connect a python script to my c++ qt project. I've searched in the internet, but all I'd found were ideas to create dynamic library from python script. I don't know how to do it, especially in QtDesigner. 
So, I made a brainstorm and I came to an idea. Why not saving an input to my python script from QtWindow to txt file, then calling python script and finally, save an output from python script to another txt file. Now I would just read real-time exchange rate from my txt file.

But I faced a problem. When I'm calling my python script, compiler says that I don't have packages used in script (requests and beautifullsoup). I checked that I have installed that libraries on my computer (terminal -> 'brew install requests', 'brew install bs4')
Unless I have it installed, Qt doesn't see it.

Do you have any idea how to say Qt that I have that stuff already installed or can you tell me an easier way to do add python script to c++ qt code or can you tell me an easier way to make web scraping? Because, based on my web searching, I did't find another that easy way to make Gui as Qt.

(Oh, and one more quick question: How can I tell Qt a path to file? As you can see in my code, I had to past full path, because Qt didn't see my file (I pasted in both in source folder, compile folder and a folder below) Remember - I'm using Mac. I know that on Windows only a filename would work.

Function in Qt c++ calling Python script:

```
void MainWindow::PythonScriptOpen()
{
    std::string filename = "/Users/username/Desktop/programming/Currency_converter/Currency_Converter/currency_converter.py";
    std::string command = "python ";
    command += filename;
    system(command.c_str());
}
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/username/Desktop/programming/Currency_converter/Currency_Converter/currency_converter.py",
>   line 3, in 
>       import requests ImportError: No module named requests

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `requests` by `pip(3) install requests`

Comment: what does number 3 in pip mean? When I paste it in terminal, it says '-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `3''

Comment: Its either pip if you have python2 installed or pip3 if you have python3 installed

Comment: I have both python2 and python3 installed. (python --version is 2.7.16 and python3 --version is 3.7.3)
I wrote "pip install requests" and it isn't still working on qt and pip(3) not working in terminal at all

Comment: `pip3 install requests`

Comment: I've changed my c++/qt code to "python3 file_name" and it's now saying "command is not found"